# An example that shows the space of functions with N Luzin property is not closed under addition

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

I'm looking for two functions $f,g $ with N Luzin property that $f+g $ fails N Luzin property.

Is there any hint how to construct them?

Comment: If it is homework then perhaps there is indeed a relatively simple construction.  If you are doing some research then this paper might help: *Ene, Vasile , On Foran's conditions A(N), B(N) and (M).
Real Anal. Exchange 9 (1983/84), no. 2, 495–501.* He takes a construction of  Mazurkiewicz of a function $F(x)$ which satisfies Lusin's condition  (N) and shows that  $F(x)+kx$ does not satisfy this condition for any   $k\not= 0$.

Comment: The Mazurkiewicz paper is *Sur les fonctions qui satisfont a la condition (N)*, Fund Math 16, 348-352 (1930).  It is cited in Saks.  Ene (who I quoted before) was much interested in exactly these kind of problems in his short life.  There might be more on the subject in his 1995 monograph, but it will take some searching through the many examples.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of two Borel functions $f,g:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ having property (N) such that $f=g$ does not have property (N). It should certainly be possible to find *continuous* functions $f,g$ with these properties; but I dont immediately see how.

Let us denote by $C\subseteq [0,1]$ the usual triadic Cantor set. It is well known that $C$ has measure $0$  and yet $C+C$ contains the interval $[0,1]$. We need the following

**Fact.** There exist two Borel functions $\alpha, \beta : [0,1]\to \mathbb R$ such that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ take their values in $C$ and $\alpha(x)+\beta(x)=x$ for every $x\in [0,1]$.

To prove the Fact, we need to show that there exists a Borel function $\alpha:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$
 taking its values in $C$ such that $x-\alpha(x)\in C$ for all $x\in [0,1]$. To show this, consider for any $x\in [0,1]$ the set $E_x:=\{ \alpha\in C;\; x-\alpha\in C\}$. This is a closed subset of $C$, hence a compact set, and $E_x\neq\emptyset$ because $C+C$ contains $[0,1]$. So we may define $\alpha(x):=\min \, E_x$. The function $\alpha:[0,1]\to \mathbb R$ is Borel (in fact, lower semi-continuous), because for any $c\in\mathbb R$ we have
$$\alpha^{-1}\bigl( (-\infty ,c]\bigr)=\{ x\in [0,1];\; \exists \alpha\in C\;:\; \alpha\leq c\;{\rm and}\; x-\alpha\in C\}\, ,$$
which is easily seen to be a closed set (by compactness of $C$). So the function $\alpha$ works by its very definition.

Consider now any Borel function $\phi:\mathbb R\to [0,1]$ which does *not* have property (N). Let $\alpha,\beta$ be the functions given by the Fact, and define
$$f(t):=\alpha(\phi(t))\qquad{\rm and}\qquad g(t):=\beta(\phi(t))\, .$$

Then $f,g$ are Borel, and they obviously have property (N) because their range is contained in $C$, which has measure $0$. But $f+g$ is equal to $\phi$, so it does not have property (N).

Comment: thanks for your beautiful answer,but how do you say that $C+C$ contains $[0,1]$?

Comment: This is not a trivial fact. Here is a link: http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masgar/Teach/2005_311/2005_03_03workshopsolutions.pdf